# WooCommerce minicart custom quantity buttons throwing an Internal error 500 on wp_admin-ajax.php

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

I am looking for some help with this as I cant seem to figure it out.
I want to add quantity selector buttons to the mini cart without using a paid plugin, I thought it would be "fairly simple"

This is the code I added to mini-cart.php ( Elementor Menu cart widget (pro) )

```
<div class="quantity-buttons">
    <button class="decrement-quantity" data-product-id="<?php echo esc_attr( $product_id ); ?>" data-cart-item-key="<?php echo esc_attr( $cart_item_key ); ?>">-</button>
    <input type="number" class="quantity-input" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $cart_item['quantity'] ); ?>" min="1" max="100" data-product-id="<?php echo esc_attr( $product_id ); ?>" data-cart-item-key="<?php echo esc_attr( $cart_item_key ); ?>">
    <button class="increment-quantity" data-product-id="<?php echo esc_attr( $product_id ); ?>" data-cart-item-key="<?php echo esc_attr( $cart_item_key ); ?>">+</button>
</div>
```

This is the jquery I used to update the quantity onChange. Added in codesnippets with 1 priority

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('.quantity-buttons').on('click', '.decrement-quantity, .increment-quantity', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            
            var button = $(this);
            var productId = button.data('product-id');
            var cartItemKey = button.data('cart-item-key');
            var quantityInput = button.siblings('.quantity-input');
            var quantity = parseInt(quantityInput.val());
            var newQuantity = quantity;

            if (button.hasClass('decrement-quantity')) {
                newQuantity = quantity - 1;
            } else if (button.hasClass('increment-quantity')) {
                newQuantity = quantity + 1;
            }

            if (newQuantity < 1 || isNaN(newQuantity)) {
                newQuantity = 1;
            }

            quantityInput.val(newQuantity);

            // AJAX request to update the quantity
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo esc_url( wc_ajax_url() ); ?>',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    action: 'update_mini_cart_quantity',
                    product_id: productId,
                    cart_item_key: cartItemKey,
                    quantity: newQuantity
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    // Update mini cart contents
                    if (response && response.fragments) {
                        $.each(response.fragments, function(key, value) {
                            $(key).replaceWith(value);
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

And lastly, this was added to function.php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_update_mini_cart_quantity', 'update_mini_cart_quantity');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_update_mini_cart_quantity', 'update_mini_cart_quantity');
function update_mini_cart_quantity() {
    if (isset($_POST['product_id']) && isset($_POST['cart_item_key']) && isset($_POST['quantity'])) {
        $product_id = sanitize_text_field($_POST['product_id']);
        $cart_item_key = sanitize_text_field($_POST['cart_item_key']);
        $quantity = intval($_POST['quantity']);

        if ($quantity < 1) {
            $quantity = 1;
        }

        // Update the quantity in the cart
        WC()->cart->set_quantity($cart_item_key, $quantity, true);

        // Calculate cart totals
        WC()->cart->calculate_totals();

        // Prepare cart fragments for AJAX response
        $cart_fragments = WC()->cart->get_refreshed_fragments();

        // Return updated fragments as JSON response
        wp_send_json_success($cart_fragments);
    }

    wp_send_json_error();
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Should I provide the URL for the live site?

I expanded the memory limit as suggested by most people, but that didnt help.
I tried resetting the plugins one by one to see if there was any collisions, that didnt help.

Answer (score 1):

On WordPress Ajax PHP function hooked in`wp_ajax_{$action}` and/or `wp_ajax_nopriv_{$action}` hooks, `die();` or `wp_die();` **is always required**, at the end of the code before the last closing `}`, to stop execution afterward, avoiding an Internal Error 500 on wp_admin-ajax.php…

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'get_my_action');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'get_my_action');
function get_my_action() {

     // Here come your code

     wp_die(); // Always at the end to stop execution afterward
}
```

See [official WordPress code example](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_ajax_action/)